# Concatenate multiple rows into a single column in teradata sql

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

Can anyone help with the examples as below, thanks a lot

```
id   color   date 

1    red     01/01
1    red     01/02
1    yellow  01/03
1    red     02/01
2    red     01/01
2    blue    01/02
2    blue    02/02
3    red     01/01
4    red     02/01
```

The ideal output should be:

```
id    pattern 
1     (red, yellow) to (red)
2     (red, blue) to (blue)
3     (red)
4     (red)
```

The result displays two things:

1. The unique pattern within one month
2. should aggregate the pattern together within time ranges

Ex, we can see that id_1 has a pattern changes on Jan from (red,yellow) but on Feb, it only has one pattern (red). Therefore the final output should be (red,yellow) to (red)

The query that I have now is

```
select drv.id, extract(month from date) as month,
trim(trailing',' from (XMLAGG(TRIM(color)',' order by date)(varchar(10000)))) as pattern from
(select id, color,
lag(color)over(partition by id, extract(month from date) order by date) as prev_color
from table
qualify prev_color <> color
) as drv
group by id, extract(month from date)
```

The query is incomplete, and it returns result like below,
but is it possible that we may return it by month?

Is there any way that we can mix using XMLAGG and partition by?

Can anyone give any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Go on. Try something.

Comment: @gig.d You better read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179035/how-does-proof-of-effort-make-a-question-better) before requesting for help.

Comment: To use XMLAGG you need a `GROUP BY`. Why not filter out "no change" rows in the inner derived table query? `QUALIFY color <> prev_color`. Also: you need the concatenation operator `||` between the column value and the separator. (And if you prefer `-` to `,` then just change that literal string in two places.)

Answer (score 0):

You need a `GROUP BY id` in the outer query. In the inner query you can filter out the 'no change' rows but also need to include the date column so you can reference it in the outer query. By default XMLAGG adds a space between items but as long as there are no spaces in the values you can easily translate that to whatever delimiter you prefer. (If there can be embedded spaces, then you can append a delimiter to each entry with the concatenation operator `||` and trim off the last one, etc.)

```
select drv.id, 
oreplace(XMLAGG(TRIM(color) order by theDate)(varchar(10000)),' ','-') as pattern from
(select id, color, theDate,
lag(color)over(partition by id order by theDate) as prev_color
from theTable
qualify prev_color is null or prev_color <> color
) as drv
group by 1
order by 1
```

I used `theDate` and `theTable` in this example because `DATE` and `TABLE` are reserved words.